# while delegate is either nil or does not implement peripheral:didUpdateValueForCharacteristic:error:?

Tags: ios, swift, core-bluetooth

In my app I want to get battery details from BLE device through Bluetooth.
I am new for `CoreBluetooth` framework.

Please give me solution for how to get Data from BLE device in app.

Below is my ViewController:

```
import UIKit
import CoreBluetooth

class BluetoothDevicesViewController: UIViewController, CBCentralManagerDelegate, CBPeripheralDelegate {

    @IBOutlet var bluetoothDevicesTableView: UITableView!

    var peripheralsArray = [CBPeripheral]()
    var centralManager: CBCentralManager?

    let YOUR_CHARACTERISTIC_UUID = "47e9ee00-47e9-11e4-8939-164230d1df67"

    var peripheralData = PeripheralData.sharedInstance

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

    }

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool)
    {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        if peripheralData.peripherals != nil {
            peripheralsArray = peripheralData.peripherals
            bluetoothDevicesTableView.reloadData()
        }
    }

    func centralManagerDidUpdateState(_ central: CBCentralManager) {
        print(central.state)
    }
}

extension BluetoothDevicesViewController: UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return peripheralsArray.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "DevicesTableViewCell", for: indexPath) as? DevicesTableViewCell

        let peripheral = peripheralsArray[indexPath.row]
        centralManager?.connect(peripheral, options: nil)

        if peripheral.state == .connected {

            cell?.circleView.backgroundColor = Common.blueColor

            peripheral.delegate = self
            peripheral.discoverServices(nil)

        } else {
            cell?.circleView.backgroundColor = Common.redColor
        }

        cell?.deviceNameLabel.text = peripheral.name
        return cell!
    }

}
```

when I run this I am getting below warning on console.

```
API MISUSE: Discovering services for peripheral <CBPeripheral: 0x282e82a80, identifier = C8C81899-0AC7-B5B6-72F4-5B9631B22D1E, name = mote 200, state = connected> while delegate is either nil or does not implement peripheral:didDiscoverServices:
```

Comment: Where is init `centralManager`? There is just a declaration. Look at how init it. And you should set its delegate

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Inside `viewDidLoad`

```
centralManager = CBCentralManager(delegate: self, queue: DispatchQueue.global())
```

---

```
func peripheral(_ peripheral: CBPeripheral, didDiscoverServices error: Error?) { 
}
```

You can follow [bluetooth](https://www.appcoda.com/core-bluetooth/)

Comment: error says you don't implement `didDiscoverServices` see edit and follow the attached tutorial

Comment: Reading characteristic value for peripheral <CBPeripheral: 0x28035c3c0, identifier = C8C81899-0AC7-B5B6-72F4-5B9631B22D1E, name = mote 200, state = connected> while delegate is either nil or does not implement peripheral:didUpdateValueForCharacteristic:error:    How to solve this?

Comment: implement this method https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corebluetooth/cbperipheraldelegate/1518708-peripheral

Comment: I do as above and I do implement the didDiscvoerServices and I even check that the delegate is not nil before calling the CBPeripheral discoverServices method and I still get the above error. It is in an extension which should not make any difference as I understand it

Comment: Once the peripheral is discovered, you have to assign its `delegate` property to the `CBPeripheralDelegate` protocol. Otherwise, you will continue to get the API MISUSE error.

Answer (score 2):

my two cents for swift iOS 15 & 16

You got this error if You trigger discovering services (calling         peripheral.discoverServices(servicesIDS) ) without proper "preparation".

When "didDiscoverServices" is called in callback, you must have already set delegate for protocol **CBPeripheralDelegate** in peripheral: i.e. you must have already issued:

```
        peripheral.delegate = self
```

for every peripheral You are going to connect.

Here I use **self** as I use an unique delegate for both BPeripheralDelegate AND CBCentralManagerDelegate, but You can delegate **whatever** object you need.

*Note again: we are speaking about "CBPeripheralDelegate", not CBCentralManagerDelegate, already set for OTHER callbacks.*